# Compile Java Springboot lombok project?

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I just inherited a java project written in 2016.
Being it a java api project i decided to download eclipse.
After loading the project I noticed that there are several compile errors. All of them regarding getters of properties in classes annotated with `@Data` (from lombok.Data)...

I suspect that this is because i didn't run a maven "Download dependencies", but thats where i get short: i have zero experience with maven, lombok, and professional java development (i know java syntax and programming, but never professionally developed for it)

How can i "download dependencies" or similar command in order to clear the compile errors?

In ultima instance i could post the complete source code but i would like to do so only if absolutely required...

Comment: How did u add it to eclipse workspace. Usually you can rightclick in the project area and choose import as maven project. This should resolve ur problem.

Comment: The dupe will explain what to do... basically you need to [download](https://projectlombok.org/download) and install lombok into Eclipse (one-time action).

Comment: And it's Maven's job to download the dependencies for you. Lombok is a special case because it needs a plugin *for the IDE*, not just for your project.